# Fax Number Regular Expression for Javascript

Tags: javascript, expression

Ok my when I tab into and out of my Fax number field I get a validation error. Is it because of the way the expression is written?

```
^(1\s*[-\/\.]?)?(\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))?\s*[-\/\.]?\s*(\d{3})?\s*[-\/\.]?\s*(\d{4})?$
```

Comment: You are accepted answers are 0 for 11. Not very encouraging...

Comment: @linuxuser27, Byron - Agreed, but take a look at the questions -- many have zero or one response. But a few could certainly benefit from an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So how is a fax number supposed to look like? `/[\+? *[1-9]+]?[0-9 ]+/` should be enough for a rough plausability check (perhaps one also has to take into account some arbitrary inserted round brackets).

Comment: When I tab into it I still get the error. When I mouse in and mouse out I don't get the error

Comment: @Moja, you need to give more information. It may not be the regexp causing the problem.

Comment: @Moja Ra: What are you talking about? Which error? Where do you tab/mouse in or out? Don’t except do get helpful answers, if you supply almost not information about the context of your question.

Comment: I did a hack around since I could not change the JS without messing up form I did a CSS hack since the fax number is not required. I appreciate the help though
label#for-tFax.error{
 color: black !important;
}

Answer (score -4):

Popfax.com offers you an alternative in fax-communication – [Internet faxing](http://en.popfax.com/Internet%20fax%20home.html). It is much easier to use and more powerful than a traditional fax machine. I use it for a long time and I'm satisfied. Cheap fax email service, faxes can be handled via email, pdfs of what you get, your own number and it's all simple.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.